# Need in wordpress conditional php to detect links to images in the content of the post / page

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a theme on wordpress, and I need a conditional if the post or page content has links to images (href = "....../fubar.jpg").

This would:

```
if (is_singular () && ** conditional true to content with links to pictures **) {
/ / This post/page has links to images 
else {} 
/ / No link to image found 
}
```

Would have to detect jpg, png and gif.

Is it possible to do this in wordpress?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Wordpress is a php framework and in php you can detect that.

What you could do, is use an xml parser like DOMDocument or Simple HTML DOM Parser to see if there are any links and process them if you find them. You could do that by opening the link and checking the file type (or process it as an image with for example `getimagesize()` and check the result).

Comment: I commend you for not suggesting regex/preg_match, which would not be robust & could also waste CPU cycles on lengthy posts

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you can use `get_the_content()` to return the content, then a library like simple html dom to find out if it has images:

```
if(str_get_html(get_the_content())->find('img', 0)){
  // there's an image
} else {
  // there's not an image
}
```